# How to measure the execution time of a servlet's method from client side java code?

Tags: java, http, servlets, time, measurement

I am writing a tool, which should be able to measure the execution time of a servlet's method from client side. Not the whole servlet's, only one method's.
To measure the running time of the whole servlet, I set a start-time then created a URLConnection with the servlet's URL, opened the connection, got the inputstream, read the inputstream, closed the connection and then set an end-time and calculated the elapsed time with a subtraction. 
But this time I'd like to measure only one method of the servlet and avoid calculating parameter reading and checking and such thing. I guess it's only possible in the servlet itself, but I need the measured value sent back to the client side program. Is it possible somehow? Or am I on the wrong path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can only imagine that this is possible if the servlet itself measures the execution and sends the info back to the client. Note that when measuring the execution of your servlet via the client, you will always measure the network's latency as well

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am aware of the network's latency. Actually I run this measurement tool and the servlet engine on the same machine, but it doesn't matter for me in this case.

Comment: @PhilippMurry My main question is (maybe it's a silly one): how to send back this info to the client side application?

Comment: Well, that's something you can implement as you wish. After measuring the execution time on the server side, you have to put it somewhere in the server's answer. Maybe formatted as JSON or XML, such as: `<execution><duration unit="ms">755</duration></execution>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You do not have control over what and how is executed on the server side being on the client side.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that too, that's why I guessed that it's only possible if the servlet measures the time itself. But how to send back this info to the client side application?

Comment: I would store this in the user session and create a simple JSP that renders the call duration value that the servlet measured and put into the session.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would use [Java Melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) for such things. Take a look, but that is *not* what you are asking.

Doing it yourself sounds imprecise. Maybe you can test the time against a call to a annother empty method.

Comment: Thank you! I took a look at Java Melody, it looks great, I think I can use that in an other project, but this time I need just a little silly tool to give me a more or less acceptable value.